# How to calculate the distance of the circumcenter to one of the sides of a triangle inscribed in a circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

In a triangle $ ABC $, the $ ∠A = 53 ° $ and the circumference measures $ 20 $, calculates the double of the distance to the $\overline{BC}\quad$side.

I do not understand the question why it asks for the distance of the circumcision to the $\overline{BC}\quad$side, and this distance varies according to the point on the $\overline{BC}\quad$side of the triangle. On the other hand, if it would be the distance from the cicuncentro to one of the points between $B$ and $C$ of the circumference, it would be $40$ ... But the answer is $24$.

[Circunference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaSJM.png)

Comment: Did you mean the _radius_ is 20?

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be a center of the circle and $OD$ be a perpendicular from $O$ to $BC$.

I think it means to find $2OD$.

Since $$\measuredangle COD=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle BOC=53^{\circ},$$
we obtain:
$$2OD=2\cdot20\cos53^{\circ}=24.07...$$

Comment: Excuse me it was my mistake, they asked me twice the distance of the circumcenter to the $\overline{BC}\quad$ side.

Comment: @Payo It's exactly, which I got.

Comment: @Michael- My mistake

Comment: Yes, Thank you
 @Michael

Comment: You are welcome!